# Xcode storyboard editor cannot zoom

Tags: xcode

new to Xcode, the editor cannot zoom, zoom options are greyed out.

[img](http://ww3.sinaimg.cn/large/6ac8e8bdgw1fbtrrpuefoj20l60jidkf.jpg)

Comment: It happen the same to me, only if I create a MacOS Application (I see you too are developing application for MacOS). 
I have not yet solved the issue... but I noticed that if I create projects for iOS, I can zoom regularly

Comment: @CristianoCostantini yes iOS project fine